# How to revert back to default ubuntu interface?

Tags: themes, configuration

I wanted to make my ubuntu 17.04 look like Mac. It worked but now I want to revert to original ubuntu interface. The commands I used are:

1. Docky:

   ```
   add-apt-repository ppa:docky-core/stable && apt-get update
   apt-get purge docky
   apt-get install docky
   ```
2. Mac OS X Lion Theme, Icons and cursors:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/macbuntu
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v7
   sudo apt-get install macbuntu-os-ithemes-lts-v7
   ```
3. Slingscold (Alternative to Launchpad)

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/macbuntu
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install slingscold
   ```
4. Replace 'Ubuntu Desktop' text with 'Mac' on the Panel:

   ```
   cd && wget -O Mac.po http://drive.noobslab.com/data/Mac/ch...
   cd /usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES; sudo msgfmt -o unity.mo ~/Mac.po;rm ~/Mac.po;cd
   ```
5. Albert Spotlight (Alternative to Mac Spotlight)

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/macbuntu        
   sudo apt-get update        
   sudo apt-get install albert
   ```
6. Enter following commands to install Apple Logo:

   ```
   wget -O launcher_bfb.png http://drive.noobslab.com/data/Mac/la... sudo mv launcher_bfb.png /usr/share/unity/icons/        
   gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-grid false;exit
   ```
7. Unity Tweak Tool to change Themes & Icons:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
   sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
   ```
8. Install Monochrome icons for Libreoffice:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libreoffice-style-sifr
   ```

   After installation go to LibreOffice menu select "Tools" - "Options" - "LibreOffice" - "View" and select "Sifr" under "Icon size and style". See following screenshots
9. install compizconfig-settings-manager

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-extra
   sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
   ```

Comment: Don't make us watch some video to find out what *you* did to your system. List the commands and any other actions you did in the post.

Comment: @muru Listed the commands I used.

Comment: You can revert using unity tweak tool

Comment: Can you tell me how ? @AbelTom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Unity Tweak Tool you can go to "Theme" and "Icons" under "Appearance".

[image]

Under Themes you can select "Ambiance" thats the theme thats installed by default.

[image]

Under Icons, select "Unity-icon-theme".

[image]